# story circa 60's a man rents a room in his house to some strange people who are time travelers

Tags: story-identification

The man notices that his renters are more than unusual. They seem uncomfortable in their clothing, and he catches the women admiring their clothing at times. He becomes friends with one of the women. She brings him into her room where she gives him a drink I believe, that makes him drugged out to the point of feeling as if he's in a dream state. She turns on a viewing device, akin to our television, and shows him things no one has ever seen. Afterwards she tells him how sorry she is that he will be caught up in something dreadful. The something dreadful is the climax to the story.

Comment: See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190821/story-about-time-traveling-tourists-who-come-back-to-witness-human-tragedies for a question with a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 4):

["Vintage Season"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?59665) by C. L. Moore and Henry Kuttner (1946). From the [wikipedia description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vintage_Season):

> Oliver Wilson is renting an old mansion to three vacationers for the month of May. He wants to get rid of them so he can sell the house to someone who has offered him three times its value, provided the buyer can move in during May. His fiancée, Sue, insists that he arrange for them to leave, so that he can sell the house, giving them enough money for their impending marriage.
>
> The tenants are a man, Omerie Sancisco, and two women, Klia and Kleph Sancisco. They fascinate Oliver with the perfection of their appearance and manners, their strange connoisseur's attitude to everything, and their secretiveness about their origin and about their insistence on that house at that time. Oliver's half-hearted attempts to evict them founder when he becomes attracted to Kleph. The mystery deepens with remarks she lets slip, with the unspectacular but advanced technology of things she has in her room—including a recorded "symphonia" that engages all the senses with imagery of historical disasters—and with the appearance of the would-be buyers, a couple from the same country, who plant a "subsonic" in the house intended to drive the residents out.
>
> Hearing Kleph sing "Come hider, love, to me" from the Prologue to Chaucer's Canterbury Tales, Oliver realizes that she and her friends are time travelers from the future. He traps Kleph into admitting they are visiting the most perfect seasons in history, such as a fall in the late 14th century in Canterbury.[6] Oliver happens to see a healed scar on her arm, which she hastens to cover and admits with obvious shame that it is an inoculation; the reason for her shame would become clear only at the end.
>
> At the end of May, more time travelers visit the house. A meteorite lands nearby, destroying buildings and starting fires—the "spectacle" that the time travelers wanted to end their visit with. Oliver's house survives, as the visitors had already known it would.

Having read the story recently in the anthology [*The Time Traveler's Almanac*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0765374242), I also remember the other plot element you mention, that the man from the present and the woman from the future had taken some kind of drug when she let slip too much about where she came from.